# Looking for a complete tutorial about process to update an electron app installed

Tags: electron

I have read lots of things about this subjet but i can't find a complete documentation. 
I succeeded to use electron-packager and electron-winstaller to get a setup.exe for my electron application.
I used electron-release-server to create a server to host my electron app to deploy.

I add in my electron app this peace of code

```
const autoUpdater = electron.autoUpdater;
var feedUrl = 'http://10.61.32.53:1337//download/:' + app.getVersion();
autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedUrl);
// event handling after download new release
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function (event, releaseNotes,       releaseName, releaseDate, updateUrl, quitAndUpdate) {

// confirm install or not to user
var index = dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, {
type: 'info',
buttons: [i18n.__('Restart'), i18n.__('Later')],
title: "Typetalk",
message: i18n.__('The new version has been downloaded. Please restart the application to apply the updates.'),
detail: releaseName + "\n\n" + releaseNotes
});

if (index === 1) {
   return;
}

// restart app, then update will be applied
 quitAndUpdate();
} );
```

But when i install my application, i have this error :

[image: exception]

In fact, i think i don't understand what to do client side but server side as well. Any help would be very appreciated !
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I used following in my version and that works (except the Tray Icon):

```
  app.on('ready', () => {
    console.warn("Starting Autoupdater")
    console.warn(app.getVersion())
    var feedUrl = 'http://ls-desktop.herokuapp.com/update/' + os.platform() + '/' + app.getVersion() + '/';
    autoUpdater.setFeedURL(feedUrl);

    tray = new Tray(__dirname + '/LS.png')
    console.log(__dirname + '/LS.png')

    console.log('created');
    autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', function() {
      tray.displayBalloon({
        title: 'Autoupdater',
        content: 'Checking for Update!'
      })
    });

    autoUpdater.on('update-available', function() {
        console.log("update-available");
    });

    autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', function() {
      tray.displayBalloon({
        title: 'Autoupdater',
        content: 'No Updates availible!'
      })
    });

    autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function() {
        console.log(" update-downloaded");
    });

    setTimeout(function() {autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()}, 10000);

    autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function (event, releaseNotes, releaseName, releaseDate, updateUrl, quitAndUpdate) {

      var index = dialog.showMessageBox({
        type: 'info',
        buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
        title: "Lornsenschule Vertretungsplan",
        message: ('The new version has been downloaded. Please restart the application to apply the updates.'),
        detail: releaseName + "\n\n" + releaseNotes
      });

      if (index === 1) {
        return;
      }

      quitAndUpdate()
    });
  })
```

Note the `setTimeout(function() {autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()}, 10000);` that is the real workaround that I used. the rest is just an nice Addition I think

Comment: Thanks for your help. I haven't try yet but i will.